# windows phone - is it possible to develop an app that will track other apps usage?

Tags: windows-phone-8, activity-manager

I'm interested to know if it's possible to develop an similar app for windows phone like those ones:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appuccino.frequencyfree
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agrvaibhav.AppUsageTracking

- those apps track other apps usage tracking and show the user how much time he spend on each app.

They are likely to be using the ActivityManager api in Android. Is there a similar API in Windows that lets me get those analytics?

Comment: can you elaborate and maybe if you know share some info why it's possible in android but not possible in iOS or wp? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible for third party apps in the current SDK as there are no APIs that allow access to that type of information. Android has a different set of APIs which allows this data to be accessed so Android apps can be created which read this data.

Answer (score 0):

Andriod is an open system and you can do almost anything. iOS and WP are closed systems. At the one side we have freedom of use, at the other side is protection and privacy. For example, there are some apps that can read and steal your history from whatsapp messenger, but it can be done in the Android device only, because you can't access other apps data in iOS or WP.